# Grub incorrectly escapes $ character in its settings

Tags: ubuntu, grub, grub2

Not sure where I make mistake but I can't escape `$` correctly in `/etc/default/grub`. I'm on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. This is what I do:

In console I edit confid by calling

```
sudo mcedit /etc/default/grub
```

I add `memmap` parameter so that string look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet memmap=3M\$11992M"
```

And follow this by invoking `sudo update-grub`. When I restart my system it hangs on boot. Going into grub settings editor **from boot menu** shows me linux param string that looks like

```
quiet memmap=3M$11992M
```

Note lack of backslash. If I press F10 to boot it hangs again. So I restart again and edit in boot editor this string to

```
quiet memmap=3M\$11992M
```

and then after pressing F10 it boots. So it almost feels like settings file gets unescaped twice.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Does the "single quote trick" as described in [grub2: needed (undocumented) character escape for kernel parameters](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/445952/comments/6) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@freddy Correctly pointed out I could use single-quote. But before I read this reply I managed to fix the problem by typing

```
quiet memmap=3M\\\$11992M
```

Looks like grub unescapes the string twice.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for any newcomer like myself.

I am working on Fedora 36 and by default GRUB2 uses BootLoaderSpec(BLS).
BLS uses `blscfg` command to read a `.conf` file in `/boot/loader/entries/`.
It seems that `$` is always eaten by blscfg regardless how many `\` you add before it.

So for @expert's solution to work, disable BLS by setting `GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=false` in `/etc/default/grub`, then generate a new `grub.cfg` by `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: Update: workaround using BLSCFG https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2102303